# Mongodb sorts by day of the week instead of actual date. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I'm new to Node.js and Mongodb so bear with me here.

I have read from multiple places that the best way to store dates is with new Date().  So before I store my dates in the Mongodb I convert them with new Date('10/07/2014'), turning it into 'Tue Oct 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'.

The problem is that if I try to run a sort on the collection it sorts them by the day of the week(Mon, Tues, Wed, etc) and not by their actual dates.  What am I doing wrong here?  Heres some actual code:

```
//get date from a field and convert it
var date = new Date($('#inputDate').val());

//after storing it in the database I call this line and it sorts it by day of the week.
db.collection('gameslist').find().sort({date:1})
```

Printing out the sorted collection their dates come out in this order, which is by day of the week and not by actual date.

```
Fri Feb 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Mon Oct 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Sun Feb 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Oct 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I've noticed in other posts when people do something like new Date() their dates don't come out like mine but instead come out with less fluff.

EDIT:  Adding my actual code.

gamelist.js file that has a function that does an ajax call.

```
dateCompleted = new Date($('#addgame div input#inputDateCompleted').val());

var newGame = {
        'title': $('#addgame div input#inputTitle').val(),
        'datecompleted': dateCompleted,
        'rating': $('#addgame div select#inputRating').val(),
    }

    // Use AJAX to post the object to our addgame service
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: newGame,
        url: '/games/addgame',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    })
```

addgame router at /games/addgame:

```
/*
* POST to addgame.
*/
router.post('/addgame', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('gameslist').insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you're storing your dates as strings instead of BSON dates.

Comment: How do I store it as a BSON date?  I went to the mongodb docs and under the BSON date section it had this as an example, var mydate1 = new Date(), which is what I think I'm doing.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code that inserts a doc with a date?

Comment: Could you update your question with a sample document or two?

Comment: I've added some more code.

Comment: Your week seems to be in a different order than mine.

Comment: Just a guess: in your `addgame` handler, what if you do `req.body['datecompleted'] = new Date(req.body['datecompleted']);` before your `insert`?

Comment: That line of code fixed the problem but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @adelprete It's because `datecompleted` gets converted to a string when posted to the server via the AJAX call.